# Proper vector notation

Tags: notation, vectors

I wrote a vector as $(a, b)$ in a maths exam but I was told it is not vector notation. However, I have seen this notation used all over this site and elsewhere. Is it correct or not?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, though there is other common notation like $ai+bj$ or $a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}$ or $a\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{y}$. Your examiner might have wanted for you to use the notation that you were using in class.

Comment: I would argue it is perfectly acceptable notation.  Of course, there are regional and personal differences and if your teacher has a particular opinion then you should satisfy your teacher for now, but at the end of the day it doesn't really matter that much how something is written but only how the something acts and operates.

Comment: It is correct but the basis is not specified, so you must be aware of which are the basis vectors. In pact, the value of the $a$ and $b$ components depend on the basis vectors that you are using. For this reason it is considered an "ordered-set" notation or "component" notation and not "vector notation". The vector notation is generally regarded as the one that is basis-independent.

Comment: @Quillo if no additional context is given it is almost always assumed that it is the standard basis.  I disagree that that is an issue.

Comment: I think also that in Algebra notation $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\equiv (a,b)$.

Comment: It is worth looking at the [wikipedia page for Vector Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_notation).  There it talks about many of the most common notations in use, including all that I have seen mentioned so far.  That said, concerns about overlapping notation with other things is valid... however worry about overlapping notation with intervals or gcd and such is largely unfounded since you will rarely be referring to both at the same time.

Comment: @JMoravitz : I have never said it is an issue, only that there are "basis independent" notations and "basis dependent ones". Moreover: the standard basis is not unique cause rotations map   orthonormal systems into orthonormal systems.

Comment: @Quillo It depends on how things are defined.  The way I am used to having it be defined is to have a very clear definition of the underlying set and of the scalar set and the operations of addition and multiplication and such.  With the underlying set being $\Bbb R^n$ there is no ambiguity as to $(1,0,0,\dots,0)$ and $(0,1,0,\dots,0)$ etc as being elements of the space and no ambiguity with regards to using these as basis vectors.  Further, these are so commonly used as basis vectors, they get the label of being called a "*standard canonical basis.*"  No other choice of basis gets that.

Comment: If you write an element of the space *as an element of the space* you don't magically forget how elements of the space are written and have some ambiguity as to what element it represented.  The element $(1,0,0)$ of the space $\Bbb R^3$ represents $(1,0,0)$ and nothing but.  If you want it to instead represent $1\cdot \beta_1+0\cdot \beta_2+0\cdot \beta_3$ for some alternate basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3\}$ then the notation should show this and make it perfectly clear.

Comment: @JMoravitz  I am just saying that: there are basis-free notations and basis-dependent notations. For example, in Physics  it is sometimes very useful to use a basis-free language, especially  (but not only) in General Relativity. I am not saying anything more than this. Of course, you can stick with what you prefer (or are used to) and it's totally fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cultural thing. I think it's perfectly fine, in general. However, to give you some examples of why someone could find it non-fine:

1. In secondary school (high school) here in Norway, students learn that the coordinates of points are written $(a, b)$, and the coordinates of vectors are written $[a, b]$. As my calculus book says, this leads to pedantic double bookkeeping, as there is no mathematical reason to distinguish between points in the plane and vectors in the plane.
2. In linear algebra, the coordinates of your everyday vectors are usually written in column form: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, or $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Writing it as $(a, b)$ makes it a row vector, which is a different kind of object.
3. As pointed out in the comments: Some don't like using coordinates at all, and want you to explicitly write your vectors as linear combinations of the unit vectors, giving something along the lines of $a\vec i + b\vec j$ or $a\vec{e_x} + b\vec{e_y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Notation is (almost) never unilateral, there are good reasons for choosing one or another. Lastly, if you use a different notation to the agreed one, you should declare it.

For instance, consider the **set** $\mathbb{R}^2:=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. Therefore the points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are, by definition of cartesian product, the couples $(a,b)$ where $a$ is in the first copy of $\mathbb{R}$, and $b$ in the second copy.

Now, $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be given the structure of vector space, so now you have $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a rule for summing points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a rule of multiplying points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by scalars. An element $v$ of this vector space (a vector, by definition), is still a point of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so to emphasize that you could write $v=(a,b)$ for some $a,b$.

But then, since most of the times we do matrix-vector multiplications in linear algebra, a convenient way of writing vectors might be $v=\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b 
\end{bmatrix}$.

The thing with notation is that it has to be declared in advance in order to be understood by others, and you choose one instead of the others depending on your goal, what you want to emphasize.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve also been told by my math teachers not to write vectors using the $(a, b)$ notation in order to avoid confusion, since that notation is often used to represent a single point on an $xy$-coordinate plane. Another answerer mentioned that it seems like something that varies by country/region, which makes sense—in the USA (the part that I’m from, at least) I was taught to write vectors as either $<a, b>$ or $a\vec x + b\vec y$.